# When I rendering my template I would like to display a function of eventHandler

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a templating with handlebars, so now my problem is simple :

When user put a letter or words or something else in the input field, the function launch the ajax call and he return the result.

But, I think, I took the problem upside down.

So if you would like to help me, you can check the code :

```js
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'

export default class Templating {

    constructor() {
        this._grabDom();
        this._addListener();

        this._getData();
        this._putData();
    }


    /* PRIVATE METHODS */

    _createBounds() {
        ['_getData', '_putData', '_prevent']
            .forEach((fn) => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this));
    }

    _putData() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this._parsing.search.length; i++) {
            let compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this._dom.cardsTemplate);

            let generated = compiledTemplate(this._parsing.search[i]);
            this._dom.cardsContainer.innerHTML += generated
        }
    }

    _getData() {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://joibor.fr/api/search.json', false);
        req.send(null);
        if (req.status === 200) {
            this._parsing = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        }
    }

    _prevent(pEvt) {
        if (pEvt.keyCode === 13) {
            pEvt.preventDefault();
            this._value = pEvt.target.value;
        }
    }

    /* END PRIVATE METHODS */

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */

    /* END PUBLIC METHODS */

    /* EVENT HANDLER */

    _addListener() {
        this._dom.searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', this._prevent)
    }

    /* END EVENT HANDLER */

    /* GRAB DOM */

    _grabDom() {
        this._dom = {};
        this._dom.cardsTemplate = document.querySelector('#cards-template').innerHTML;
        this._dom.cardsContainer = document.querySelector('.section-bottom__template');
        this._dom.searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-search-input');
    }

    /* END GRAB DOM*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="section-top">
    <form class="form">
        <label class="form__label" for="">Lieux</label>
        <input type="text" class="form__input js-search-input" placeholder="...">
    </form>
</div>
<section class="section-bottom">
    <h2 class="section-bottom__title">Les membres qui se trouvent à Reims</h2>
    <div class="section-bottom__template"></div>
    <script id="cards-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="cards__position">
                <img class="cards__image" src="{{image}}" alt="profil 1">
                <div class="cards-content">
                    <div class="about about--flex">
                        <p class="about__name">{{name}}</p>
                        <p class="about__city">{{city}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="text__content"><span class="text__content__cat">Disponible : </span> {{start}} <span class="text__content__cat">au</span> {{end}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="place">
                        <p class="place__content"><span class="place__content__cat">Nombre max de voyageurs : </span> {{max}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</section>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, the templating works but not the search I can't solved this problem.

Comment: Are you sure your code snippet will run here?

Comment: I edited with the HTML. But I use gulp you need to running this part of code on server because I used ajax